# The problem of deploying multiple chart on one figure (Python Plotly)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I faced a problem. I want to deploy two graphs on one figure, but this has very different values on Cartesian axis… and when I do it one of them turns into a line

````
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
main_data = pd.read_csv(‘12.txt’,delimiter = ‘;’,names=[‘Received’,‘ExchTime’,‘OrderId’,‘Price’,‘Amount’,‘AmountRest’,‘DealId’,‘DealPrice’,‘OI’,‘Flags’],
nrows= 50000,low_memory=False)

deals = main_data[[‘ExchTime’,‘DealPrice’]][3:]

deals1 = deals[deals[‘DealPrice’]!=‘0’]
times = deals1[‘ExchTime’]
deals2 = deals1[‘DealPrice’]

open_int_1 = main_data[[‘ExchTime’,‘DealPrice’,‘OI’]][3:]
open_int_1 = open_int_1[open_int_1[‘DealPrice’]!=‘0’]
open_int_true = open_int_1[‘OI’]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
go.Scatter(
x=times,
y=deals2,

))
fig.add_trace(
go.Histogram(
x=times,
y=open_int_true,
marker={‘color’:‘green’}
))

fig.show()

result:[enter image description here][1]```
 

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIu1w.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use are called 'subplots'.

See the documentation here: https://plotly.com/python/subplots.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Comment: This is not the result I need. I need one figure and many graphs on it